# Structured format for bilingual texts?

Tags: text, data-structures, format

I want to format a parallel text so that words and sentences are aligned in two or more languages. Most of the structured text formats I found are XML based and are used by translation tools or Bible software. I want to find or create a format suitable for reading foreign language texts. The reader will have the ability to select words and see their equivalent in the source or target language.

I've thought about using multidimensional arrays with words aligned by index. But the issue is that there are many words and phrases which do not have a one-to-one mapping. So then I thought about using a relational database, such as SQLite. I could have a table for each language with each word indexed by id and join tables for the alignment. But then the question is how to represent punctuation, paragraph breaks, and other necessary formatting.

Are there other data structures or formats I have not thought of? Ideally it would be a flat-file, markup format to facilitate editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you have one or more text files, one in Language A, one in Language B, etcetera, the latter being a translation of the first.  With that assumption:

You could mark up your plain-text file(s) with uniquely numbered tags around words, phrases and/or punctuation, e.g.: "Dear Sir, How are you today?" translated to German becomes: "Sehr geehrter Herr, wie geht es dir heute?":

```
<Language-English:<11:<4:<1:Dear> <2:Sir><3:,>> <10:<7:<5:How are> <6:you>> <8:today><9:?>>>>

<Language-Deutsch:<11:<4:<1:Sehr geehrter> <2:Herr><3:,>> <10:<7:<5:wie geht> <6:es>> <8:dir heute><9:?>>>>
```

My German is fairly rusty, so I may not have the tags quite correct, but they should still show what I have in mind.

As you can see, the entire sentence and its parts each have their own tags.  When displaying the text, each `<n:` `>` pair would be stripped out, and could be replaced with an underline or some other form of highlighting to indicate the groups.  Of course, there could be multiple underlines/highlights (this example would have up to four).  When clicking on (and visually emphasizing) the highlight on the text in Language A, the corresponding highlight(s) in Language B (and other languages if present) would also be emphasized.

Naturally, it would most likely be the job of a human translator to do the markup as automating the actual translation and applying tags at that point is a non-trivial task.

However, a UI where elements in each language could be simultaneously highlighted then marked as being equivalent could facilitate the process of generating the marked-up file(s).

As to your other considerations (arrays and databases), they seem to be something of an over-complication.  You would still have to somehow mark-up your texts so that they could be loaded into these structures, since words or even phrases in one language don't necessarily have a 1:1 transliteration to the equivalent in another language), and usually can't easily be translated by machine.  Once you have the markup, talking about array/dictionary/database/other structures becomes a bit irrelevant, and only of concern to the UI programmer.

EDIT:

On further consideration, the tags may not be perfectly nested, and may be split, so you may need a `<n:` `:n>` tag pair, to allow partially overlapping and split tagged areas.  E.g.:

```
<1:The:1> <2:black:2> <1:dog:1> <3:and <4:the dog:3>'s puppies:4>
```

has the fragments: "The dog", "black", "and the dog", and "the dog's puppies".

Edit 2:

You could support multi-texts by just having the tag pair IDs unique across all languages:

```
EN: "The Knight's coat of arms was defaced"
DE: "Das Wappen des Ritters wurde verunstaltet"
FR: "Le blason du Chevalier a été abîmé"

<1:The Knight's:1> <2:coat of arms:2> <5:<3:was:3> <4:defaced:4>:5>.
<2:Das Wappen:2> <1:des Ritters:1> <3:wurde:3> <4:verunstaltet:4>.
<2:Le blason:2> <1:du Chevalier:1> <5:a été abîmé:5>.
```

As you can see tags 1, 2, 3 & 4 are applicable to English and German, and tags 1, 2 & 5 are applicable to English and French.  The tags could quite easily be split and partially overlapping.

Comment: I had not thought about nesting tags within tags. It's an interesting idea, but a custom parser will be needed. Also, this format would only support bitexts because the words/phrases are tightly coupled to the target language. I like the simplicity of this idea. Other data structures are indeed more complex, but could provide more flexibility or other features.

Comment: Yes, a custom parser and a custom UI would be required.  You didn't specify that it had to use off-the shelf components.

Comment: See my Edit 2 for multitext support.

Comment: No, it doesn't need to use off-the-shelf components, but creating a new kind of markup language along with a parser that supports split and nested tags is no small feat. Moreover, it will have to be loaded into some other type of data structure in memory to support highlighting in javascript or analysis in other programming languages. I do like this approach, so I'll go ahead and reward you the bounty. Thanks!